# Replace dashes with underscores within Any type of bracket

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace dashes with underscores within any bracket in a string.
Example String:

```
[a]-[a-gamma]+(a-alpha)*{a}-{b-gamma}+[a]
```

replaceAll=?
output

```
[a]-[a_gamma]+(a_alpha)*{a}-{b_gamma}+[a]
```

Comment: `replaceAll()` supports Regular Expressions, which is what you'll want. Pseudocode for the regex: Check for an underscore within open and close brackets

Comment: Not possible duplicate... `its exact duplicate` of question highlighted by @AmalMurali... OMG.. you were the one who asked it!!! Y another question of same type!!!

Comment: @DarkHorse: That comment is auto-generated when you close-vote a question as a dupe of another one.

Comment: I haven't got the right yet :P... but @Xeshan J .. Y post another question when you have ticked it correct in your own previous question?

Comment: The question is different, even if the goal is the same since now it needs to work with any kind of brackets.

Comment: There is a difference between that question of mine with this question. In that question i asked for Square brackets only but in this question i asked for All types of brackets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to do this one using [lookbehind mechanism in regexp](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
String input = "[a]-[a-gamma]+(a-alpha)*{a}-{b-gamma}+[a]";
String result = input.replaceAll("-(?![\\[\\{\\(])","_");
```